# Return immutable state with a dynamic key

Tags: javascript, immutability, redux

I am using Redux and my store kind of look like this

```
const initialState = {
  'ui': {
    'showModal': {}, // contains the `userId`: true || false
  }
}
```

My reducer look something like

```
case actions.OPEN_MODAL:
return Object.assign(
  {},
  state,
  state.ui.showModal[action.userId] = true // <- I think it is actually mutating instead of returning a copy of the state
)
```

How can I return a copy of the state and not mutating it with `action.userId` as a key of `showModal`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you're mutating. Instead, you should assign a new object to do this:

```
const newState = {
    ui: {
        showModal: {},
    }
};
newState.ui.showModal[action.userId] = true;

return Object.assign(
    {},
    state,
    newState,
)
```